# Does ARM gdb not have TUI layout support?

Tags: microcontroller, arm, debugging, openocd, gdb

If it run

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb -tui myProject.elf
```

This returns

```
 TUI mode is not supported
```

If I run it without the -tui flag and try to call `lay` or `layout` in gdb it does not recognize the command, however if I run normal `gdb` not the `arm-none-eabi-gdb` layout works but of course I get an error about unknown architechture "ARM"

So, is there a way to step through my C code using GDB and have a more visually appealing experience? Aside from using an IDE

Comment: There are multiple frontends you can use with GDB, such as DDD or Insight or ... Did you try any of these? Why don't you want to use a decent IDE?

Comment: A lot more info is needed. Where you downloaded this program or with what package it came with, or did you  build it yourself and which version it is. Is it a Windows or Linux program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TUI feature is optional upon building GDB. So it probably depends who compiled your `arm-none-eabi-gdb`.

There is a configuration option `--enable-tui` that needs to be set in order to build GDB with TUI.
It is mentioned in [the GDB documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Configure-Options.html).

If you didn't and don't want to build GDB yourself, you could ask your provider about the feature.